# What's the opposite of "extending the deadline"?

Tags: vocabulary, antonyms

Extending or pushing a deadline means giving more time to work on a project. But what if you want to say you are changing it so that the task is due sooner?

What are the words or expressions I could use?

Comment: People with a 'go-getter' attitude might say they were *accelerating the project* as a way to cast a positive light on it.

Comment: What did you find when you looked in a thesaurus for antonyms of *extend*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most often you will encounter *moving up the deadline*.

Comment: Or curtailing the lead time.

Comment: Or _pulling it in,_ but I think I hear _moving up_ most often.

Answer (score 16):

One would **shorten a deadline**.

Comment: Another word for "shorten" would be "abridge"

Comment: The deadline runs *across* the timeline representing a point in time: its length makes no difference :)

Answer (score 7):

Looking up dictionaries I found that ***prepone*** is actually a [legitimate word](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prepone).

> to reschedule to an earlier day or time: *Our Wednesday meeting has been preponed to Tuesday afternoon at 3:00.*

It makes sense etymologically as well since *postpone* is a composite of *post* (after) and *pone* (place, position). Example sentences using the words *prepone* and *preponement* can be found [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Citations:prepone#English).

EDIT: As per the OED this word has etymological roots in Latin very much the same as the corresponding antonym. It derives from the classical Latin word *praepōnere* meaning to place in front.

Comment: Legitimate only in Indian English, as your link says. Not a bad thing in itself, but care is needed elsewhere.

Comment: Not according to citations found on the wiki link provided it seems.

Comment: All the citations on the wiki link strengthen the case **against** *prepone* other than in Indian English.

Comment: *praepōnere*: 'place before', in the sense of 'give a higher priority/ importance', preference https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/praep%C5%8Dnere -- not the antonym of *postpone*

Comment: @Kris How about coining something else then: antepone. :)

Answer (score 2):

The term *extending the deadline* is itself incorrect. You can only *move* the deadline, farther or nearer. "deadline: the latest time or date by which something should be completed."

The deadline runs **across** the timeline, representing a point in time: its length makes no difference :)

A similarly incorrect, though very common, phrase is *extending the Last Date/ Due Date*. The last date or due date is a point in time. One should be saying "extending the time for (completion/ action/ etc.).

Comment: Natural language ≠ formal logic.  Interpreted utterly literally, “extending the deadline” doesn’t quite make sense, but its idiomatic meaning is very well-established; it’s perfectly correct English.

Comment: @PLL It was never the case  that the expression is grammatically incorrect; in fact, it's almost idiomatic. However, you've agreed it's illogical, which was my point :)

Comment: @Kris, the very first line of your answer says, "The term *extending the deadline* is itself incorrect". That doesn't sound so much like your point was that it is simply formally illogical.

Comment: But more importantly, even if that was your point, you are then just making a comment that is not even linguistically relevant -- how does this answer the question at all?

Comment: @BenLee The second sentence contains the answer. Rest of the narration explains it. https://www.google.com/search?q="shorten the deadline"

Comment: @PLL & 3 others: https://www.google.com/search?q=incorrect

Answer (score 2):

You can say advancing the deadline.

Refer to [Advance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advance) .

5:  to bring forward in time; especially :  to make earlier

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

"Bring forward the deadline."

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever heard "Moving the schedule up" or "Fast-tracking the schedule" (or project). Mind, I'm not commenting on correctness, just referring to my BS Bingo sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I heard someone said 'pull in the project', that's what you mean, I'm not a native English speaker, anyone can confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard the phrase "tightening up the schedule", used to signify that low-priority tasks would be cancelled to move the finish date up.

Answer (score 0):

Rescheduling any event so it's nearer to the present is often called ***bringing it forward***, whereas the reverse is *pushing it back.*

> *The deadline was brought forward by one week*

This idiom is defined in the Macmillan Dictionary, amongst other places:

> **bring forward:** to change the date or time of an event so that it happens earlier